# ActiveRecord, only objects with a nil parent record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, squeel

I've got a basic forum set up. I want the posts#index action to only show records where parent_post_id is nil, and therefore not a reply post. I've got squeel installed, but I'm not sure if I have it set up right.

```
  #app/controllers/posts_controller.rb
  def index
    @forum = Forum.find(params[:forum_id])
    @posts = @forum.posts.where{ |post| post.thread == nil }
  end

 #app/models/post.rb
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :replies, :class_name => "Post"
  belongs_to :thread, :class_name => "Post", :foreign_key => "parent_post_id"
end

#config/initializers/squeel.rb
Squeel.configure do |config|
  # To load hash extensions (to allow for AND (&), OR (|), and NOT (-) against
  # hashes of conditions)
  config.load_core_extensions :hash

  # To load symbol extensions (for a subset of the old MetaWhere functionality,
  # via ARel predicate methods on Symbols: :name.matches, etc)
  config.load_core_extensions :symbol

  # To load both hash and symbol extensions
  config.load_core_extensions :hash, :symbol
end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
@posts = @forum.posts.where{ "posts.parent_post_id is null" }
```

See

*Conditions* section of 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Base.html

We say "posts" not "post" since the name of the table is "posts"

**Added** You don't need squeel for this type of simple where clause. We say "is null" since that is the proper SQL syntax for finding nil values, not "== nil".

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be working. `Post Load (0.1ms)  SELECT "posts".* FROM "posts" WHERE "posts"."forum_id" = 1` is still what's coming through in the console, and all the posts are coming through, not just the top-level ones.

Comment: Try entering the statements in the rails console itself. You're missing the added where clause somehow.

Comment: Yeah, it turns out I was messing it up in the view layer